# Use both read() and readlines() with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I currently have the following:

```
    filecmd = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'diff', commit, commit2, file],
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=null)
    gitoutraw = filecmd.stdout.read()
    gitoutrawlines = filecmd.stdout.readlines()
```

This causes gitoutrawlines to be blank. How can I set both variables? I've tried using just `gitoutraw = filecmd.stdout.read()` and converting it into a list, but I've been unsuccessful.

Comment: Why do you need both?

Comment: I'd like to be able to use both forms later on in the program. If I can only use just one instance of `filecmd.stdout`, then I want to be able to convert the output of the list/data to the opposite, whichever is easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gitoutrawlines = gitoutraw.split("\n")`

Comment: `gitoutrawlines = gitoutraw.splitlines(True)` will give the same actual output

Comment: And it seems splitlines might be a bit cleverer than plain old split.  Good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

if you do :

```
output,error = filecmd.communicate()
```

`communicate` give tuple of (stdoutdata,stderror)

output will contain the desired result. Now you can manipulate it as you want.

you can use the Tony way